# Upper bound for solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, upper-lower-bounds

I have been trying for days to understand where the following bound in a [paper by Wei & Yan](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021782407000864) comes from:

[image: 1]

More precisely,
$
U(r):=(1+r^2)^{-1}
$
for every $r\in[0,\infty[$ and $\lambda_j,\mu>$ are constants. I am grateful for any suggestion.